# Authentication failed. mongodb with laravel 5.4.36

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5.4

Try to connect the mongodb with laravel
Laravel version `5.4.36`
Downloaded the packages

```
composer require jenssegers/mongodb:3.2.0
jenssegers/mongodb-session
jenssegers/mongodb-sentry
```

config/database.php

```
'mongodb' => [
                'driver'   => 'mongodb',
                'host'     => 'localhost',
                'port'     =>  27017,
                'database' => 'mydb',
                'username' => 'usrename',
                'password' => 'password',

],
```

Mongo db version `3.4.16`

```
use mydb
db.createUser( { user: "username", pwd: "password", roles: [ "readWrite" ] } )
```

Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Hisnode extends Eloquent
{
    protected $connection = 'mongodb';
    protected $collection = 'somecollection';
}
```

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Mongomodel;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class ConnectmongoController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $node = Mongomodel::all();
    }
}
```

While call controller i got error
Authentication failed. I dont know why it is happen . I create a user in mongo and put that user name and password.